# Sensible way to output content of dictionary as valid html tags?

Tags: c#

I am trying to generate hreflang tags like so:

```
<link hreflang="en-DE" rel="alternate" href="/en-DE" />
```

I currently am putting together my dictionary as below, and I thought I could use a 2nd foreach loop to generate the tags with the key value pairs:

```
public static IHtmlString HrefLangLinks(this PageData currentPage)
{

    var hrefLangTags = string.Empty;
    var availablePageLanguages = currentPage.ExistingLanguages.Select(culture => culture.Name).ToArray();

    Dictionary<string, string> langs = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    var contentLoader = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IContentLoader>();
    var urlResolver = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<UrlResolver>();

    foreach (string cultureName in availablePageLanguages)
    {  
        var culturePage = contentLoader.Get<PageData>(currentPage.ContentGuid, new LanguageSelector(cultureName));
        var culturePath = urlResolver.GetVirtualPath(culturePage.ContentLink, culturePage.Language.Name);
        langs.Add(cultureName, culturePath.GetUrl());

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in langs)
        {
            hrefLangTags += ("<link hreflang=\"{0}\" rel=\"alternate\" href=\"{1}\" >", langs.Keys, langs.Values);

        }
    }

    return new HtmlString(hrefLangTags);

}
```

Is there a simple and elegant way to iterate through the dictionary and create my tags?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you even using a dictionay? You could just iterate through "availablePageLanguages" and append the needed data to your "hrefLangTags".
So like this:

```
public static IHtmlString HrefLangLinks(this PageData currentPage)
{

var hrefLangTags = string.Empty;
var availablePageLanguages = currentPage.ExistingLanguages.Select(culture => culture.Name).ToArray();

var contentLoader = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IContentLoader>();
var urlResolver = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<UrlResolver>();

foreach (string cultureName in availablePageLanguages)
{  
    var culturePage = contentLoader.Get<PageData>(currentPage.ContentGuid, new LanguageSelector(cultureName));
    var culturePath = urlResolver.GetVirtualPath(culturePage.ContentLink, culturePage.Language.Name);

    hrefLangTags += String.Format("<link hreflang=\"{0}\" rel=\"alternate\" href=\"{1}\" >", culturName, culturePath.GetUrl());

}

return new HtmlString(hrefLangTags);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, you could do it in `linq`, it's a *little* more succinct:

```
public static IHtmlString HrefLangLinks(this PageData currentPage)
{
   var contentLoader = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IContentLoader>();
   var urlResolver = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<UrlResolver>();

   var links = currentPage.ExistingLanguages.Select(culture =>
         {
            var culturePage = contentLoader.Get<PageData>(currentPage.ContentGuid, new LanguageSelector(culture.Name));
            var culturePath = urlResolver.GetVirtualPath(culturePage.ContentLink, culturePage.Language.Name);
            return $"<link hreflang=\"{culture.Name}\" rel=\"alternate\" href=\"{culturePath.GetUrl()}\" >";
         });

   return new HtmlString(string.Join("",links));
}
```

<sub>***Disclaimer**: This is totally untested or verified.*</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Your method does not make use of the first principle of [SOLID (Single responsibility)](https://codeburst.io/understanding-solid-principles-single-responsibility-b7c7ec0bf80). You want to return links based on data input. But you are generating the needed data in the same method that is responsible for converting it to a list of IHtmlStrings.

The code beneath is may not be compact but it's a bit easier to read because the nested foreach loop is removed. You could call the method below by chaining them like: `CreateLanguageLinksList(CreateWorkingLanguageDictionary(currentPage))` or do it like so

```
var languageDictionary = CreateWorkingLanguageDictionary(currentPage);
var listOfIHtmlStrings = CreateLanguageLinksList(languageDictionary);
```

The code above is easier to read, so the cognetive load is less straining on the mind.

```
public Dictionary<string, string> CreateWorkingLanguageDictionary(this PageData currentPage)
    {
        var languageDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        var contentLoader = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IContentLoader>();
        var urlResolver = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<UrlResolver>();

        foreach (string cultureName in availablePageLanguages)
        {
            var culturePage = contentLoader.Get<PageData>(currentPage.ContentGuid, new LanguageSelector(cultureName));
            var culturePath = urlResolver.GetVirtualPath(culturePage.ContentLink, culturePage.Language.Name);
            languageDictionary.Add(cultureName, culturePath.GetUrl());
        }

        return languageDictionary;
    }

    public IList<IHtmlString> CreateLanguageLinksList(Dictionary<string, string> langs)
    {
        var htmlStringList = new List<IHtmlString>();
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in langs)
        {
            htmlStringList.add(new HtmlString("<link hreflang=\"{0}\" rel=\"alternate\" href=\"{1}\" >", langs.Keys, langs.Values));
        }

        return htmlStringList;
    }
```